# How can i divide my shiny app into two parts?

Tags: r, shiny

i am working on shiny app.i want to divide my app into two parts. i want like that when i click on 1st tab it redirects to specific portion and same as for 2nd tab.Both scripts will be different from one another there will be no mutual functions or anything between them.how can i do this ?

Comment: Please add more information and/or a min reprex https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: means when run my shiny app ,there should be Two option like A and B , when i click on A it consist of file input option and result of that input and same as B. A and B both has no connection.Both input will be also different.

Comment: Still vague but take a look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tabsets.html